# in vscode default formatter for JavaScript, how to avoid space before brace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

here is my code

```
function foo(){
}
```

after passing it through the default formatter(alt+shift+f) I get:

```
function foo() {
}
```

(note the added space in the first line)

My question is: how do I set up the formatter so it does not add the space?

Comment: Every style guide I've ever seen is either `function foo()\n{` or `function foo() {`, I've never seen any guide advocate for `function foo(){`... But if that's your preference, you're gonna need something other than the default formatter.

Comment: thanks for that, do you know which one? I tried a lot of them